# How to expand the product of Laguerre polynomials into a sum of series？

Tags: summation, power-series, laguerre-polynomials

In the course of my research, I needed a formula and found it, but I can not understand the derivation process of the formula. How to extract the $t^n$ and get the $\theta(m-p)$ in the last step? Can you explain how to get the last step? Thank you.

**The derivation process in the literature is as follows：**

The generating function for the Laguerre functions is {$\phi_m(x_3;\alpha)$}

\begin{align}\frac{\alpha ^{1/2}e^{-(1/2)\alpha x_3 (1+s)/(1-s)}}{1-s}= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} s^m\phi_m(x_3;\alpha)\end{align}

Thus

\begin{align*}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}dx_3\frac{\alpha ^{1/2}e^{-(1/2)\alpha x_3 (1+s)/(1-s)}}{1-s}e^{-\beta x_3}\frac{\alpha ^{1/2}e^{-(1/2)\alpha x_3 (1+t)/(1-t)}}{1-t}\\
&\quad=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s^m t^n\left \langle m|e^{-\beta x_3}|n \right \rangle\\
&\quad=\frac{\alpha}{(\alpha+\beta-\beta t)-(\beta+(\alpha-\beta) t) s}\\
&\quad=\alpha \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} s^{m} \frac{(\beta+(\alpha-\beta) t)^{m}}{(\alpha+\beta-\beta t)^{m+1}}\\
&\quad=\alpha \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} s^{m} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^{n} \sum_{p=0}^{n} \theta(m-p) \frac{(m+n-p) !}{(m-p) !(n-p) ! p !} \frac{(\alpha-\beta)^{p} \beta^{m+n-2 p}}{(\alpha+\beta)^{m+n+1-p}}
\end{align*}

where $\theta(n)=1$ for $n=0,1,2, \ldots$ and $\theta(n)=0$ for $n=-1,-2,-3, \ldots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We obtain
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\left(\beta+(\alpha-\beta)t\right)^m}{(\alpha+\beta-\beta t)^{m+1}}\\
&\quad=\frac{\beta^m}{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^{m+1}}\,
\frac{\left(1+\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\beta}t\right)^m}{\left(1-\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}t\right)^{m+1}}\\
&\quad=\frac{\beta^m}{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^{m+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-m+1}{k}\left(-\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\right)^kt^k\left(1+\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\beta}\right)^m\tag{1}\\
&\quad=\frac{\beta^m}{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^{m+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{m+k}{k}\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\right)^kt^k\sum_{p=0}^m\binom{m}{p}\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\beta}\right)^pt^p \tag{2}\\
&\quad=\frac{\beta^m}{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^{m+1}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\left(\sum_{{k+p=n}\atop{k\geq 0,0\leq p\leq m}}\binom{m+k}{k}\binom{m}{p}
\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\right)^k\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\beta}\right)^p\right)t^n\tag{3}\\
&\quad=\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\left(\sum_{{p=0}\atop{0\leq p\leq m}}^n\binom{m}{p}\binom{m+n-p}{n-p}\frac{(\alpha-\beta)^p\beta^{m+n-2p}}
{(\alpha+\beta)^{m+n+1-p}}\right)t^n\tag{4}\\
&\quad\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{p=0}^{\min\{m,n\}}\frac{(m+n-p)!}{(n-p)!p!(m-p)!}\,\frac{(\alpha-\beta)^p\beta^{m+n-2p}}
{(\alpha+\beta)^{m+n+1-p}}\right)t^n}\tag{5}
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we make a *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ and expand the binomial.
- In (3) we calculate the *[Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series)*.
- In (4) we substitute $k=n-p$ and collect terms.
- In (5) we use $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

Comment: Thanks for your perfect solution. However, I encountered difficulties in solving similar problems using this method. Could you please help me once more? You can download the file including the problem from [here (file link)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bs7czrb8e0sqjmz/NewProblem.zip?dl=0). Thank you very much.

Comment: @likelee: I prefer to restrict my activities of this kind to MSE. Since you did a good job in presenting your problem, I suggest to also give it a try at MSE. This way there is also the chance for others in the community to provide you with helpful answers. Kind regards,

Comment: I invite you to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4214042/how-to-proof-equations-with-the-aid-of-laguerre-functions). If you are busy, it would be appreciated if you could help me
proof the last two equations, or point out the key points of solving the problem.Thank you.

Comment: @likelee: At the time I'm on holidays. Hopefully someone else can meanwhile provide helpful information. Otherwise I'll have a look at it, when I'm back. Kind regards,